# How can I access the profile name/id of a user in Google accounts

Tags: oauth

I'm using OAuth 2.0 to allow people to sign in to my website using a variety of different accounts (Google, Facebook, Windows Live, Twitter and OpenID). Currently I can get access to a unique profile ID using Facebook and Windows Live, but I can't find that information for Google.

It appears I can access it through the OpenSocial API, but that uses OAuth 1.0 for authentication.

Answer (score 0):

Try - https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo

Of course - you need to add this to the scope - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile